# How do I go from getCookies() to a string in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Input: I use [HttpServletRequest](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) class in Java that has [`getCookies()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies()).

Output: I need to set request's cookie field as a string:

```
// foo=123123;bar=222
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
String cookie = "foo=123123;bar=222"
connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
```

Is there a built in method to convert the output of [`getCookies()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies()) to string?

I do realize I can probably iterate over all cookies and create such a string manually, but it looks like I'm missing something.

Answer (score -1):

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
String cookie = request.getHeader("Cookie");
connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the getHeader() method to get the Cookie header string:

```
String cookie = request.getHeader("Cookie");
```